pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: Unknown error 524, What is going on?
I'm working on a function that takes text and turns it into a .wav file using pyttsx3 on an RPi4B, then using pygame it plays the .wav file (I know pyttsx3 has a built in function for this but we got different and harder to diagnose errors from it), but it seems to be conflicting with ALSA, it works on windows just fine but on the RPi it breaks
this is the code here (For inputOutput):
'''File to utilise the speaker system'''
import pyttsx3 
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()
mix = pygame.mixer
mix.init()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[12].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 155)


# Function to convert text to
# speech
def SpeakText(command):
    # Initialize the engine
    engine.save_to_file(command, "Words.wav") 
    engine.runAndWait()
    mix.music.load("Words.wav")
    mix.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue
    mix.music.unload()
    if os.path.exists("Words.wav"):
        os.remove("Words.wav")
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")


the full error that is being raised is:
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.26.5, Python 3.11.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://ww.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user/Project-Sigmund/main.py", line 4, in <module>
     import inputOutput #name of file
   File "/home/user/Project-Sigmund/inputOutput.py", line 7, in <module>
     mix.init()
pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: Unknown error 524

I've tried various different threads but nothing is working
This program does work on windows and generates the expected result, just not on RPi
